# Bounding $P(X \le \tau)$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am trying to upper bounding $P(X \le \tau)$ where $X$ is non-negative r.v. and where $\tau \le 1$.

I have become aware of the [Reverse Markov](http://planetmath.org/reversemarkovinequality) inequality that says that, if  $P(|X|\le a)=1$ then for $\tau \le E[X]$

\begin{align}
P(X \le \tau) \le \frac{\tau-E[X]}{a-\tau}
\end{align}

Some facts about $X$:

X=|a*Z-b*Y|   where $Z$ and $Y$ are independed and uniform on $[0,1]$

My question are there extension of this inequality?
Is there a simpler version of the inequality since my r.v. is non-negative?
Is there general literature on reverse markov inequalities?

Thank you

Comment: Can you list what facts you know about X? Just that its non negative?

Comment: Done. I added how it is generated.

Comment: +1Thanks...that will give people a LOT more to work with :-)

Comment: Markov type inequalities are called Concentration Inequalities? Is there a general theory of these?

Answer (score 2):

The general field is called the [Concentration of Measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_of_measure). This is also a [nice](http://www.econ.upf.edu/~lugosi/anu.pdf) overview.

[Chernoff's bound is applicable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Theorem_for_additive_form_.28absolute_error.29) since you actually know the distributions. Basically, substitute $e^{\lambda x}$ as the function in markov's inequality. This will lead to you using the moment generating function of X on the RHS of the inequality.

The MGF of the sum of two independent RVs is the product of their MGFs...a nice feature in your case. The absolute value will still give you some trouble, but you'll get a better bound with the chernoff approach.